# Android Studio, how to install “JVM Debugger Memory View” plugin

Tags: android-studio, plugins, jetbrains-ide

As introduced in this post https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2016/08/jvm-debugger-memory-view-for-intellij-idea/
seems the “JVM Debugger Memory View” is useful plugin. But could not find a way to install it.

With Android Studio 4.0.1, the preference/plugins is like:

[image]

But don't see how to install it in Android Studio 4.0.1?

Also saw a post https://hackernoon.com/a-useful-memory-debugger-plugin-for-android-studio-2d9d95bddc24, and it shows a button "Install JetBrains plugin…"  in the plugin page, which I couldn't find in my Android Studio.

Anyone knows how to install the plugin “JVM Debugger Memory View”?

-- following @Rajab, but my Android studio 4.0.1 does not have the "Memory View icon in debug pane:
[image]

Comment: That plugin is out of date (I mean: not compatible with latest builds as per Versions tab). IntelliJ IDEA has it built-in since some version (2017.x): https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/analyze-objects-in-the-jvm-heap.html. No clues about Android Studio (not using it). Try going to "Settings/Preferences | Keymap" and type "memory" there -- will there be any relevant actions in the results?

Comment: P.S. You can try downloading plugin file (https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/8537-jvm-debugger-memory-view/versions/stable/40089) and install from a file (on Plugins screen, look for the appropriate entry under the Cog icon). I'm certain that it will fail (incompatible) .. but worth checking it though...

Comment: @LazyOnee thanks! Does not find anything from the "Keymap -- memory", and the downloaded plugin, as you suspected, got "incompatible" error. sigh.

Comment: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-172077 (about extracting it into a plugin, 2017) & https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-175146 (AS is quite slow with that plugin, Android runtime specifics) , https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/38437408 (AS: about disabling this functionality, 2017).

Comment: Just in case if it's still there: see if there are some configs that may enable this: open `Registry...` (if AS has it of course) via "Hep | Find Action...", look for `memory` or `debugger` related entries (just start typing and then Up/Down). `debugger.enable.memory.view` in particular (I doubt it will be there, but please check)

Comment: Don't think these are about the same, but anyway: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/158918663, https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/158918664 --> https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/memory-profiler

Answer (score 0):

To install plugins you should change from installed pan to marketplace pan in android studio:

[image]

Comment: tried in the "maketplace", and not seeing the "JVM Debugger Memory View” there.

Comment: Well it seems like, the Memory view has been integrated to the Debug tool window, please, see the screenshot https://plugins.jetbrains.com/files/8537/screenshot_16824.png . It can be accessed while you are debugging your app

Comment: tried on my Android Studio 4.0.1 does not see the "Memory View" in debug pane (I added the screenshot in the question). What else it needs to do in order to see the "Memory View"?